# Google Calendar sortorder & future events not working

Tags: android, json, google-calendar-api

i am trying to get only the future events in a descending order, i am using the google calendar api fields but future events and descending are not working

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/XXXXXXXXXXXgroup.calendar.google.com/events?singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&sortorder=descending&max-results=10&futureevents=true&key=XXXXXXXXX

when i use the above url, it gives a json of events starting from past month and goes all the way in ascending order to next year..

what could be the reason?

Answer (score 3):

`Future events` and `descending` are parameters supported by v2 of the Calendar API. For v3, which you are using according to the URL, you can use [orderBy](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) in combination with `timeMin` / `timeMax` to get only the future events you want. Note that orderBy returns events in ascending order, so you will need to get the list of events and reverse the list yourself.